# Upgraded my node.js express app to v0.8.2 and getting no method 'enter' error

Tags: node.js

The application was running under v0.6.6, now I get the following when the application first starts up. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
< events.js:80
<       this.domain.enter();
<                   ^
< TypeError: Object localhost:3111 has no method 'enter'
<     at HTTPServer.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:80:19)
<     at Server._listen2 (net.js:926:10)
<     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same error when I updated node from 0.6.6 to 0.8.9. I tracked the problem to: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3922

In my case a module that was inheriting from node events also contained a property called 'domain'. Renaming this property to something other than 'domain' was a workaround that worked for me. (Alternatively, refactoring to not inherit from events would be even better.)

If you are relying on a 3rd party module that hits this issue then your choices may more be limited until the bug is addressed in node or the 3rd party module is updated with a workaround.